# How to use query with operator dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

In  my front end, I have a filter for tags, and it sends to backend an array of strings and i have that search in the database with it.

The problem is that I'm having five different columns and in some cases the query can be return true (there is value in the column) but also can return false (there is not value in the column), ie, I have that make a query dynamic using `OR` and `AND`.

I tried to use `CASE WHEN` but I didnt have success with it.

My query is like this:

```
SELECT
  *
  FROM
table AS cll
WHERE
cll.fill IS NULL

AND
  (
    (
    CASE 
      WHEN cast(cast(integerField as text) = ANY(ARRAY['15', '']) as boolean) = TRUE 
        THEN cast(integerField as text) = ANY(ARRAY['15', '2']) AND 
        ELSE cast(integerField as text) = ANY(ARRAY['15', '2']) OR

      END
    )
  )

//others
```

But I have the error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "END"
>           ^

Someone can help me ? I dont know why..

Query that I need:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table AS cll
WHERE
    cll.filled_by IS NULL
AND
    cast(integerField as text) = ANY(ARRAY['15', 'existCity']) //TRUE
OR //OR if is false or AND if is true
    city = ANY(ARRAY['15', 'existCity']) //TRUE
OR //OR if is false or AND if is true
    country = ANY(ARRAY['15', 'existCity']) //FALSE
```

Result expected:

```
integerField    |      city      |       country
15                  'exitsCity'          'Brazil'
```

Comment: Your have a lingering `OR`.

Comment: I used `OR` but `OR` return just a last true...

Comment: He mean the last `OR` is orphan remove it or add another condition

Comment: I cant remove it, because it makes it be dynamic to make the next condition

Comment: But if I let him, it doesnt work :/

Comment: What you mean dynamic?  Show us some example of data and expect result so we can understand the problem

Comment: Great, 1 minute.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Done, check now, please

Comment: We need a sample of the original table, otherwise how we will know how to get that result.    Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: Also include how/what is the filter you get from the front end

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza is a array of strings, i said on question.. thank you for the tips

Comment: Again show us the source Table and the array.

Answer (score 0):

untested, but you can try

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table AS cll
WHERE
    cll.filled_by IS NULL
    AND (   case
                when    cast(integerField as text) = ANY(ARRAY['15', 'existCity'])
                then    cast(integerField as text) = ANY(ARRAY['15', 'existCity'])
                        and city = ANY(ARRAY['15', 'existCity'])
                        and country = ANY(ARRAY['15', 'existCity'])
                else    cast(integerField as text) = ANY(ARRAY['15', 'existCity'])
                        or city = ANY(ARRAY['15', 'existCity'])
                        or country = ANY(ARRAY['15', 'existCity'])
            end)
```